# Special N character

Tags: symbols, characters

I'm trying to write a special N character in TeX, it looks like this:

[image]

I tried using `$\mathcal{N}$`, it similar but not quite the same.

Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try ``\mathscr{N}``?

Comment: @Vincent Thanks, it does work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the [mathrsfs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathrsfs) package and write `\mathscr{N}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % or: \usepackage[scr=rsfs]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{N}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several packages that provide variants of . If you’re using the legacy toolchain with 8-bit fonts, `mathalpha` provides a comprehensive list of available alphabets, with scaling and the ability to load as either `\mathscr` or `\mathcal`. The documentation also has font samples.

In the modern toolchain, with `unicode-math`, there are about a dozen fonts you can load with `\setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{some-font.otf}`. The default `\mathscr` command is based on Euler Calligraphic, rather than Ralph Smith formal script.

In particular, `\setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr}, Scale=MatchLowercase, StylisticSet=1]{STIX Two Math}` gets you a similar, but less-slanted, .